# VueJS checkbox with v-model and the ability to add a class

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to output the value of individual checkboxes and also add a class to the label when the checkbox is checked. I can do one of the other but not both together. If I add :value="attendance" the output works as individual instances but the adding of the class doesn't work and if I add value="attendance" then it treats the 2 checkboxes as one value.

Can someone help please?

```
     <div class="container">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm">
                          <label
                            class="btn btn-outline-primary label-in-filter"
                            :class="{
                              showattendances:
                                showattendancesisChecked('attendance'),
                            }"
                            v-for="attendance in uniqueattendances"
                            :key="attendance"
                          >
                            <!-- <input
                              value="attendance"
                              id="attendance"
                              name="showattendances"
                              class="ck-in-filter"
                              type="checkbox"
                              v-model="attendances"
                            /> -->

                            <input
                              id="attendance"
                              name="showattendances"
                              class="ck-in-filter"
                              type="checkbox"
                              :value="attendance"
                              v-model="attendances"
                            />
                            {{ attendance }}
                          </label>
                        </div>
                        <p v-for="attendance in attendances" :key="attendance">
                          {{ attendance }}
                        </p>
                      </div>
                            </div>
 methods: {
 showattendancesisChecked(value) {
      return this.attendances.includes(value);
    },}
```

Comment: is 'uniqueattendances' defined somewhere? in the method u use the variable this.attendances - is that the one u are trying to refer?

Comment: Yes 'uniqueattendances' is defined. It is either 'full-time' or 'part-time'. If I console.log  the value of the checkbox and 'attendances' and toggle the 2 buttons on and off I get:

true Proxy {0: 'full-time'}
true Proxy {0: 'full-time', 1: 'part-time'}
false Proxy {0: 'full-time'}

How can I get the value and add a class? Thanks for helping.